# Installing TFS 2015 Express on Bootcamp fails - CreateATFileCacheFolder Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am trying to install TFS 2015 Express on a dual boot macpro with windows 10 installed on bootcamp. I have visual studio pro 2015, SQL Express 2014. All pre-checks pass without a hitch and IIS is fully configured. The installer is insisting on writing the cache folder on Macintosh HD (D: drive) which happens to be read only, I would rather it doesn't. I cant figure a way to do a custom install or override the default action. Following is an extract from the configuration log.

```
[Info   @23:44:29.298] +-+-+-+-+-| Running CreateATFileCacheFolder: Creating Application Tier file cache folder ... |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @23:44:29.314] 
[Info   @23:44:29.314] +-+-+-+-+-| Creating Application Tier file cache folder ... |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Starting Node: CCRTATFILECACHE
[Info   @23:44:29.314] NodePath : Container/Progress/CCRTATFILECACHE
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Creating 'D:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache' ...
[Error  @23:44:29.314] 
Exception Message: Access to the path 'D:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureCreateFolder.Run(ActivityContext context)

[Info   @23:44:29.314] Node returned: Error
[Error  @23:44:29.314] The Application Tier file cache folder could not be created.  See the configuration log for additional details.
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Completed CreateATFileCacheFolder: Error
[Info   @23:44:29.314] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Execution results:
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Overall result: Failure
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Nodes completed: 1
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Nodes succeeded: 0
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Nodes skipped: 0
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Nodes with errors: 1
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Nodes with warnings: 0
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Number of error messages: 1
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Number of warning messages: 0
[Info   @23:44:29.314] Number of info messages: 0
[Error  @23:44:29.314] Activity failed.
```

Is there a way to override this behavior? Your help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The TFS file cache folder is used to cache frequently accessed TFS resources for more efficient communication with your server. You should place this directory on a disk with at least 50GB of free space.

You can give the DriverD "Write" permission to install TFS first, then go to TFS admin console, under Application Tier tab, you can change the path of File Cache Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Cece that would have worked however I found another solution which avoids changing the permissions of the other drive or installing additional software. I figured the windows prefixes drive letters (i.e. D:) to file paths and by removing it, I would basically make the resource invisible. After searching, I found and followed this http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-hide-a-drive-in-windows to remove the drive letter. The configurator only saw a single drive and proceeded without a hitch. On completion I reassigned the drive letter and everything is good. Thanks for your help.